# Cookie less sessions in PHP

Tags: session-cookies, sessionid, php

For one of my project's (weird) requirements, I want to use cookie less sessions. At the same time, "session.use_trans_sid" can not be turned on :(

Does anybody please let me know if is there any other way out ??

Thanks
Manish

Comment: Why can’t you turn *session.use\_trans\_sid* on?

Comment: Dumb answer is "That is the requirement" .. But I guesss it is for avoiding the SESSIONID getting displayed in the URL

Comment: Then there is no way to do it. The session ID needs to be transferred somehow. Either per cookie or per URL.

Answer (score 2):

Make a custom session manager  that identifies the user based on, for example, IP address and user agent and other identifying factors (as IP+UA might not and probably will not be unique). Another (ugly) solution is to just implement the use_trans_sid functionality yourself by adding a session identifier GET parameter to every link by hand (if it's a small site) or with a hidden form (that's non-standard).

Comment: The combination if IP address and user agent identifier is *not* unique!

Comment: No, it necessarily isn't - but it was simply an example.

Comment: And a *very* inadvisable example.

Comment: Edited the answer to reflect that it was definitely not meant to be a complete solution.

Comment: The link in the answer has rotted.

Comment: Link removed as it went to the wrong place now. Usual issue with off-site links

Answer (score 1):

If you really want sessions without cookies, you can always put the SID in all your URLs manually. People used to do this quite a bit. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The only other option is to keep the session data on the client and pass it back and forth to and from the server with each request, although technically that would be a sessionless architecture.
That means that for GETs each link has to be rewritten to include all the session variables, and for POSTs they have to be included as hidden fields.